# Typescript error using new apollo server version in nestjs application

Tags: typescript, nestjs, apollo-server

I've updated `apollo-server-plugin-base` to v3.2 in my nestJS application and now I do get two typescript errors for this simple nestjs plugin:

```
import { Plugin } from '@nestjs/graphql'
import {
  ApolloServerPlugin,
  GraphQLRequestListener
} from 'apollo-server-plugin-base'

@Plugin()
export class LoggingPlugin implements ApolloServerPlugin {
  requestDidStart(): GraphQLRequestListener {
    console.log('Request started')
    return {
      willSendResponse() {
        console.log('Will send response')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I do not understand the error at all. Therefore I need some help.

**requestDidStart():**

```
TS2416: Property 'requestDidStart' in type 'LoggingPlugin' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ApolloServerPlugin<BaseContext>'.
  Type '() => GraphQLRequestListener<BaseContext>' is not assignable to type '(requestContext: GraphQLRequestContext<BaseContext>) => Promise<void | GraphQLRequestListener<BaseContext>>'.
    Type 'GraphQLRequestListener<BaseContext>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<void | GraphQLRequestListener<BaseContext>>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]
```

**willSendResponse:**

```
TS2322: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(requestContext: GraphQLRequestContextWillSendResponse<BaseContext>) => Promise<void>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you should be making `requestDidStart` an asynchronous function, either by returning a void promise `return Promise<void>.resolve();` or by adding the `async` keyword to the method declaration `async requestDidStart()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me, and adds a bit more flavour to the logging:

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Plugin } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { GraphQLRequestContext } from 'apollo-server-core';
import { ApolloServerPlugin, GraphQLRequestListener } from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';

@Plugin()
export class LoggingPlugin implements ApolloServerPlugin {
    logger: Logger;

    constructor() {
        this.logger = new Logger('ApolloServer');
    }

    // Fires whenever a GraphQL request is received from a client.
    async requestDidStart(requestContext: GraphQLRequestContext): Promise<GraphQLRequestListener> {
        this.logger.log(
            'Request received:\n' +
            requestContext.request.query +
            '\nvariables:' +
            JSON.stringify(requestContext.request.variables)
        );
        return {
            async willSendResponse() {
                // console.log('Will send response');
            },
        };
    }
}
```